# Building a basic Addthis page

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

Im trying to build a basic page with the Addthis code inside.

The code I am using is :

```
<html>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>test    </TITLE>
         <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
         <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

         <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'>    </script>
         <script type='text/javascript' src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
   </HEAD>
<body>

 <div> 
   <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
  <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
   <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count">    </a>
   <a class="addthis_button_tweet">    </a>
   <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit">    </a>
   <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style">    </a>
  </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=felix001">    </script>
   <!-- AddThis Button END -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I run the page in a browser I get a blank screen. Am I missing anything obvious ?

Thanks,

Comment: looks like the `src` attribute on your vary last script tag is missing something (an `http:` perhaps)...

Comment: [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/7mZap/).

Comment: Still doesnt work in the browser though ?

Comment: If I upload the html/js to a webserver it works, but it just does not work locally (??)
Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work locally because the src tag is using "//s7..." and trying to determine the protocol based on the parent page.  In your case, while running locally, the parent page probably looks like:

file://c:\blahblah\index.html

and therefore the protocol is file:// which doesn't work (it needs to be http or https).  This is done to make it easy for users to copy the code into a site that is either http or https without having to make changes to the code.

To fix this locally, just prepend http so it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=felix001"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but only got a single hyperlink for twitter (??)

Comment: Some of the third-party buttons like Facebook and Pinterest might not work because of the same problem where they don't recognize file:// as a valid protocol because they won't let you actually share a page/image with the file:// protocol. I would recommend avoiding opening files directly and setting up Apache or IIS locally so you can view pages correctly in your browser.